# When one is clicked, disable the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

So I have a mini slide menu in my website there is a menu you can choose what you want to read. There are points to click, when u clicked it the point get a red background. 
But there is a problem.
When i click one point and then an other point the first clicked point have to lose his background.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div id="slide_button" onClick="clicked(this);"><dir class="button_1"></dir></div>
<div id="slide_button" onClick="clicked(this);"><dir class="button_2"></dir></div>
<div id="slide_button" onClick="clicked(this);"><dir class="button_3"></dir></div>
<div id="slide_button" onClick="clicked(this);"><dir class="button_4"></dir></div>
<div id="slide_button" onClick="clicked(this);"><dir class="button_5"></dir></div>
```

**Here is my JS:**

```
function clicked(slide_button) {
    slide_button.getElementsByTagName("dir")[0].style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

***HERE IS AN EXAMPLE ON*** [**FIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/399Dm/).

*My "QUESTION IS" what i have to do to solve that?

What should I pay attention?*

Comment: id of html elements should be unique per document!

Comment: -should +have to (unless you want to create invalid markup which is causing trouble)

Comment: Look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/sUzuH/) pure javascript with event delegation and without loops.

Comment: [Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/sUzuH/1/) add comments.

Comment: i like this please take it in an answere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix your HTML becaue your `id` values aren't unique. In fact, you don't even need `id` values, so you should use "slide_button" as a class. You can then use it to select all the buttons:

```
<div onClick="clicked(this);" class="slide_button"><dir></dir></div>
<div onClick="clicked(this);" class="slide_button"><dir></dir></div>
<div onClick="clicked(this);" class="slide_button"><dir></dir></div>
<div onClick="clicked(this);" class="slide_button"><dir></dir></div>
<div onClick="clicked(this);" class="slide_button"><dir></dir></div>
```

The CSS needs to be changed now so "slide_button" is a class selector, instead of an `id` selector:

```
.slide_button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As for clearing the background, clear all of them before coloring the selected one red:

```
function clicked(slide_button) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('slide_button');
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].getElementsByTagName('dir')[0].style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
    slide_button.getElementsByTagName('dir')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NZ3su/1/)

This uses just JavaScript with no JQuery, but if you are using JQuery, you might as well use it here. The code is a lot shorter and easier to follow.

Here's a JQuery version:

```
$(function() {
    $('.slide_button').click(function() {
        var $button = $(this);
        $button.children(':first').css({ backgroundColor: 'red' });
        $button.siblings().children(':first').css({ backgroundColor: '' });
    }); 
});
```

Note: This registers a click-handler, so you can get rid of the "onclick" attirbutes.

[jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/C384Y/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to select all other points and set their background to none.

Or remeber which point is selected and on select another just remove background on last and remeber current point, then set its background to red.

See fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/399Dm/5/

Answer (score 1):

At first id should be unique per element.

```
<div class="slide_button"><dir class="button"></dir></div>
<div class="slide_button"><dir class="button"></dir></div>
<div class="slide_button"><dir class="button"></dir></div>
<div class="slide_button"><dir class="button"></dir></div>
<div class="slide_button"><dir class="button"></dir></div>
```

Second, you should store reference of clicked element if you want later remove background color, and instead of inline event handlers or binding all elements would be better if you use event delegation.

[***Demonstration***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/sUzuH/2/)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

// getting parent node of divs, due to bind click event. then 
    var ele = document.querySelector(".slide_button").parentNode, 
        prev = null; // store previous clicked element

    ele.addEventListener("click", clickHandler); // event handler.

    function clickHandler(e) {
        var t = e.target; // get target of clicked element

        // filter by target node name and class. edit: removed class checking
        if (t.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "dir") {
            // checking value of prev !== null and it's not same element.
            if (prev && prev !== t) {
                prev.style.backgroundColor = "";
            }
            prev = t; // store clicked element
            t.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: I updated my answer, since in your website you using different class name per elements, so, i removed from if statement of classList.contains() method.

Comment: do u have a new script or waht :)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the fiddle so that it works hopefully as you plan.
http://jsfiddle.net/399Dm/8/ There you go!

```
var forEach = function(ctn, callback){
    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(ctn, callback);
}

function clear(element, index, array) {
  element.getElementsByTagName("dir")[0].style.backgroundColor="";
}

function clicked(slide_button) {
    forEach(document.getElementsByClassName("slide_button"), clear);
    //.style.backgroundColor="";
    slide_button.getElementsByTagName("dir")[0].style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/399Dm/17/)***

jQuery

```
$('.slide_button').click(function(){
    $('.slide_button dir').css("background-color", "inherit");
    $(this).find('dir').css("background-color", "red");
});
```

HTML - Your markup is invalid because you have duplicate ids. Make them classes as below instead.

```
<div class="slide_button" >
    <dir class="button_1"></dir>
</div>
<div class="slide_button">
    <dir class="button_2"></dir>
</div>
<div class="slide_button">
    <dir class="button_3"></dir>
</div>
<div class="slide_button">
    <dir class="button_4"></dir>
</div>
<div class="slide_button">
    <dir class="button_5"></dir>
</div>
```

CSS change

```
.slide_button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: really nice but it should be horizontally

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different method than @atlavis but a similar result.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2AGJQ/

Answer (score 0):

If you can look at the following [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/siva_hari/gJLr5/), I used jQuery to get what you want.